# Fedex Quotes Issue

Tags: magento-1.9

Someone purchased 3 items totaling around 80 lbs and fedex gave them an option of $55 however, when I ran fedex quote using my credential (Fedex official website) it quoted me $350.

Whats wrong with that ?

Comment: check log and compare magento request with Fedex official website

Comment: be it depends on number of box in shipment and  total bill weight (higher from weight and dimensional weight)